# можно ли в одном sql запросе поставить 2 update php

Tags: php, sql, update

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста можно ли в одном sql запросе поставить значение update - а чтобы сразу обновились две поле, если да то приведите пример пожалуйста

Comment: `update table1 set field1=  1, field2=2;`

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможно. Синтаксис может отличаться, уточните в документации к подключенной  СУБД. Например, может быть так:

```
UPDATE t1  
SET t1.a = t2.a, t1.b = t2.b
FROM t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

или так:

```
UPDATE t1  
SET (a, b) = (SELECT a, b FROM t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```